# Cypress: Is it possible to use cy.route to stub out requests with specific path in its request body?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have several different API calls all goes to the same url, which is `/api`. What differentiates them is in their request body, where there is a `path` specified for each different API call. So the request looks like this

```
url: '/api',
method: 'POST',
headers: ...,
body: {
  headers: {X-Amz-User-Agent: ".", Content-Type: "application/json"}
  method: "GET"
  operation: "describeEndpoint"
  path: "/endpoint"
  region: "us-east-1"
}
```

And I know I can use `cy.route` to stub out API calls like this

```js
cy.route({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/api',
      status: 500,
      response: {},
    })
```

But since there are many other API calls also go to this endpoint `'/api'`, I want it to be specifically targeted to the `describeEndpoint` call, which has `"/endpoint"` in its `path` so this stub doesn't affect other API calls. I wonder if it is possible to do it with `cy.route`.

By the way does anyone know why is it that the `method` in the request is `POST` while the `method` in the request `body` is `GET`? This is how the API request looks like in my app and I cannot understand the discrepancy here